# SVG: Need border on hover only on the rectangle and not the text within

Tags: css, svg, hover

I have a rectangle and some text within it. The entire rectangle and the text within it is clickable, and opens a new web page when clicked.

I need to use styling within my SVG document such that, when I move the mouse over the text or the rectangle, it should show a border around the rectangle. Because everything in the box is clickable, the `<path>` and `<text>` elements are within an `<a>` element. So, if a do something like this, I get a border around the path as well as the text.

```
<style type="text/css">
  <![CDATA[
    a:hover
    {
    stroke:#26a9e0
    }
  ]]>
</style>
```

How can I get border just around the box, even when the mouse is moved over path or text?

> Edit: This is an edit to the original question that was originally posted as an answer by the OP

Thanks for the response. Putting in more code here for clarity

```html
<a aria-labeledby="itemTitle" cursor="pointer" xlink:href="http://some-link" target="_blank">
   
       <path id="path3856" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#26a9e0" d="m808.52,167.06,0,58.146,3.7936,0,0-58.146-3.7936,0z"/>

       <path id="path3858" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFF" d="m811.83,167.06,0,58.146,172.16,0,0-58.146-172.16,0z"/>

       <text id="text3860" style="text-anchor:start;text-align:start;" font-weight="normal" xml:space="preserve" font-size="17.65748024px" font-style="normal" y="191.36598" x="822.92633" font-family="Segoe UI" fill="#000000">Some Text</text>

</a>
```

So, you can see that I have  which includes  and . The effect I need is to have a border around the box, which is denoted by  in the code. The important thing is that border should show both on moving the mouse over the shape as well as text. So, if do what you suggested, i get the border on the rectangle only when the mouse is on the rectangle. If i move it over the text in the rectangle, the border goes away.

To fix this, if I do

```html
a:hover
    {
      stroke:#26a9e0;
      
    }
```

I see the border on the box as well as the text when I move the mouse over it.

This is a little tricky to explain, i know. I hope I am making myself clear.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from your code, as it's incomplete (e.g. need to see the rectangle), but I suspect what you need is to use the `rect` element instead of the `a` element.  Currently you're setting the stroke color when on an `a`, try this instead:

```
rect:hover
{
stroke:#26a9e0
}
```

Of course, it would be better to me more specific (this would affect all rectangles) so you'd want to make it a particular class (say `glow`) and use `rect.glow` instead of just `rect`.